# Coding Raspberry Pi with an ADC - SPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, adc

I am trying to connect an analogue to digital converter to the raspberry pi. As far as I am able to understand, the RPi doesn't support Bi-directional SPI mode. The adc I am using says it is SPI compatible but only has the inputs SCLK, CNV and outputs CLKOUT+ and CLKOUT- and SD0+ and SD0-. This leads me to understand that it will only work with bi-directional SPI as there is only the serial data out. I am thinking of using a PWM for CNV (which I think CE), GPIO clock for SCLK and then an interrupt on the falling edge of the GPIO clock to just digitally read each bit from the adc. I don't understand SPI in detail but from what I've read quite often it requires sending data in order to receive it. Do you know if the setup I mentioned (without using SPI) will work? Or am I missing something about SPI and the adc will work with that while not in bi-directional mode?

We are using the Raspberry Pi 3 b
adc - http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/232316fa.pdf

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Further down the readme under "supported mode bits" it says Bidirectional mode is currently not supported. Despite the description near the top

Answer (score 0):

Read the data sheet carefully, in particular pages 8 and 9. I suggest that you tie CMOS/LVDS pin to ground to enable CMOS mode. Then use only the "+"-pins. Use the SCK for SPI clock, SD01+ for SPI data input to the Rpi. Connect a GPIO pin to CNV.
Also observe that the RPi runs at 3.3V, and the ADC's max rating is also 3v3, that is running the IC right to the edge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently I can run the ad with a gpio clock and pwn for chip select, and am using CMOS. Can you just use the read pin? Do you know of a similar example or some basis for the code? I'm sorry I'm a complete beginner with SPI and the raspberry pi. Officially was looking at python but the python API specifically says it's not reliable for real time applications, so C if possible. I've been looking at the wiringpi library but it doesn't seem to specify much about SPI (although is loosely included). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Try Googling python-spi. Python is fine for spi and other fast io, as long as you use the Linux kernel drivers, and don't need to bit-bang GPIO pins in realtime.

Comment: I have managed to get it working using a pwc and gpio clock however the signals are distorted by ringing such that the result is iffy. The dta sheet does day the ADC requires a jitter free signal. Do you know if sclk via SPI would be any cleaner or still have similar noise?

Comment: I doubt that it would be any cleaner if you use the SPI clock. How long are the wires between the RPi and the ADC?